# Backbone View Fetching Twice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm writing a (supposedly) simple Backbone app to interface with Wordpress (using JSON API Plugin). I can display all of the current posts on a page using a collection, but having trouble fetching a single post. (Note, ajax prefilter is used here).

```
var NewsItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/get_post/',
    parse: function(response){
        return response.post;
    }
});
```

My view:

```
var SingleNewsItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    id: "single-view",
    initialize: function(data) {
        this.render(data);
    },
    render: function(data) {
        var that = this;
        var singleNewsItem = new NewsItem();
        singleNewsItem.fetch({
            data: $.param({"id": data}),
            success: function(returnitem) {
                var template = _.template($('#single-news-item-template').html(), {newsitem: returnitem});
                that.$el.html(template);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error retrieving item');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The correct URL is being called once and displayed on the screen. However, very quickly afterward, the same URL is called with id=undefined, which results in the over-writing on the View of the news item, with bad data.

I've placed an alert() in the click handler and it is not firing twice due to ghost issue - this is something going on with fetch() which I can't figure out!

Comment: My guess is you're calling render explicitly from outside the view, probably when you create the instance, as well as automatically when the view is initialised.

Comment: Calling `fetch` inside `render` is strange. You'd usually call `render` in response to a `fetch`.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using a library called "BackStack" also. I guess it was calling the render function, and I was calling it from within the initialize function also. Thank you very much for your help - all sorted! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Also typically you would do the fetch on initialize and show a loading spinner and then listen for 'sync' and set a flag like this.isReady = true and re-render the actual view